# Finding repeated names in a file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

Hi i have a txt file with last name and name of people, now i want do use egrep to only display the names of the people with the same last name. I have no idea how i could do this. Thanks for help
my txt looks like this:

```
snow john
snow jack
miller george
mcconner jenny
```

and the output should be:

```
john 
jack
```

---

I've currently tried running:

```sh
cat names.txt | cut -d " " -f 1 | awk 'seen[$]++'
```

...but this fails with an error:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
     >>> seen[$] <<<
awk: bailing out at source line 1
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for `sort`

Comment: You want to *group by* last name and display those groups with more than one member, or you want to select all people with a *specific* last name?

Comment: i want to have them grouped by last name but only display the first name of all the members with the same last name.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: i tryed: cat names.txt | cut -d " " -f 1 | awk 'seen[$]++'

Comment: Show sample data and expected output by editing your question.

Comment: as an aside, in general, calling `cat` with only one argument is a code smell: It means you probably shouldn't be using `cat` at all. `<names.txt cut -d " " -f 1` or `cut -d " " -f 1 names.txt` are both more efficient than `cat names.txt | cut ...`.

Comment: @user9035730 You may note that the accepted answer is not fault proof as it fails for duplicate entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a typical 2-pass approach with `awk`:

```
awk 'NR == FNR {freq[$1]++; next} freq[$1]>1{print $2}' file file

john
jack
```

**Reference:** [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)

Comment: This will not work if there are duplicate entries  in the file, say two `snow john`

Comment: I didn't see a case of duplicate full name in question. If op has that case I can easily tweak this command.

Comment: It makes sense to assume that two people may have the same name, so you may tweak this a bit..

Comment: I just realized that it is already working for duplicate name entries. If OP allows duplicate full names and expected output is something else then please update the question or comment.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is your friend. With a single pass approach, you could achieve your result using a memory technique where you store last record in variables

Given an input file as follows:

```
$ cat file
snow john
snow jack
miller tyler
snow leopard
kunis ed
snow jack
snow miller
snow miller
sofo mubu
sofo gubu
```

...the following shell command uses a single `awk` pass to generate correct output:

```
$ awk 'count1[$1]==1 && ++count2[name[$1]]==1{print fn} # replica of next step with prev record values
       count1[$1]++ && ++count2[$2]==1{print $2} # our main logic
       {name[$1]=$2} # Here,we keep a copy of current record for next passes
      ' file
john
jack
leopard
miller
mubu
gubu
```

---

**Note:** The final answer includes the suggestion from  [@ordoshsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7304514/ordoshsen)  mentioned in [[ this ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47581438/finding-repeated-names-in-a-file/47581928?noredirect=1#comment82126887_47581928) comment. For more on awk, refer [[ the manual ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html).

Comment: you cannot print the first of the duplicates' names with this attitude

Comment: @Ordoshsen, ...well, this *could* be adopted if you had a second pass -- if, for instance, you used the stream this `awk` code generates as an input file (process substitution, etc) passed to the `-f` argument of `grep` as a list of words to search for (with appropriate other options -- `-F` and `-w`, maybe?). So it needs work, but it *is* salvageable.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy We may use a memory approach to prevent a second pass. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: @Ordoshsen Please see the updated answer, which introduce a few more conditions and some program memory.

Comment: @sjsam I hate to be that guy, but since you put in the effort in... It still fails when you put in for example 'snow john, smith jack, snow jim' as it only prints jim and not john. I took the liberty to change your script a little.
`awk 'count1[$1]==1 && ++count2[name[$1]]==1{print name[$1]} count1[$1]++ && ++count2[$2]==1{print $2} {name[$1]=$2}'`
Anyways I'm pretty much happy with your answer now

Comment: @Ordoshsen . Aww  it requires an array  in the memory part for it to be truely a memory.. Please note, i have incorporated your suggestion to my answer.